# Throw error on behalf function making a call

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, electron

I'm dealing with the following conundrum. I have a class that can dispatch multiple calls, and acts as a sort of wrapper for Electron's `BrowserWindow` class. As such, the `BrowserWindow` object is reused between multiple calls, which are all async `Promise`-returning functions. Think of something like this:

```js
class WindowWrapper {
  window = null;

  constructor() {
    this.window = new BrowserWindow();
  }

  async callX() {
    await this.window.callX();
    return;
  }

  async specialCallX() {
    await checkPreCondition();
    await this.window.callX();
    return;
  }

  // ... and a couple more, you get the picture
}
```

The issue is, during any of the calls a window may be opened. The user is free to close these windows, after which a `close` event is emitted by `BrowserWindow`. This does mean that the current function call has to be aborted. As such, I would like to throw an Error from the function that caused the BrowserWindow to be shown. Yet, creating event handlers for every function independently is problematic:

```js
class WindowWrapper {
  // ...

  async specialCallX() {
    // Subscriptions have to be repeated for every call
    const closeHandler = () => throw new Error('UserAbort');
    this.window.addListener('close', closeHandler);

    await checkPreCondition();
    await this.window.callX();

    // This listener might not be removed if either of the 
    // above functions throws an error themselves
    this.window.removeListener('close', closeHandler);
    return;
  }
}
```

Therefore, I am considering having a single listener for the event in the constructor, after which a function calls ownership of the errors when it starts executing. Thus, I wonder if it is possible to throw an error on behalf of another function:

```
class WindowWrapper {
  constructor() {
    this.window = new BrowserWindow();
    this.window.on('close', this.handleError);
  }

  handleError(e) {
    throw new Error('UserAbort');
  }

  async specialCallX() {
    // Does this even work? What could I do here to make
    // sure the error is thrown as part of this call?
    this.handleError.bind(this);

    // ...
  }
}
```

such that this call is able to catch the `UserAbort` error:

```js
new WindowWrapper().specialCallX()
  .catch(e => console.error('User Aborted Action!));
```

I might be missing some options here, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Lei

Comment: maybe the registry pattern might work for you.  where the calls that open the window, register with a registry helper, and handle your close events, as required.  this gives you more separation. I found this blog, you might want to have a look at it: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2014/01/28/killing-switch-statements-with-a-registry-an-example-and-screencast/